# How to store a reference to a struct inside a class

Tags: c#

I have a main form which opens a second form as a dialog.

On the dialog form close, I would like to edit an external struct so all the form settings are captured on close.

I pass a struct into the dialog form constructor, but it seems it is copied when I save it to a private property inside the class.

How can I maintain a link to the external struct?

Below is the relevant code for the dialog form.

```
public partial class MASettingsForm : Form {
    private MovingAverageSettings _settings;

    public MASettingsForm(ref MovingAverageSettings settings) {
        InitializeComponent();
        _settings = settings;
        SetUI(_settings);
    }


    public void SetUI(MovingAverageSettings settings) {
        maTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = (int)settings.type;
        maCalcMethodComboBox.SelectedIndex = (int)settings.calcMethod;
        maCalcValueUpDown.Value = settings.calcPeriod;
        maOffsetUpDown.Value = settings.offset;
        applyToHeikenAshicheckBox.Checked = settings.useHeikenAshi;
        OnTypeChange();
    }

    // User clicks ok to apply the dialog form settings
    private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

        _settings.type = (enum_Ma_Type)maTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        _settings.calcMethod = (enum_Calculation_Method)maCalcMethodComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        _settings.calcPeriod = (int) maCalcValueUpDown.Value;
        _settings.offset = (int)maOffsetUpDown.Value;
        SetExtendedValues(_settings);

        Close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know C#, but in C++, you would declare _settings as a reference

Comment: Why do you need a struct, why not a class?

Comment: You should be using classes by default and structures in specific situations where it is appropriate. This is obviously not one of those situations, given that you're asking how to make it behave like a class.

Comment: The reason it needs to be a struct is because it's used as a primitive type that is exported in a DLL file.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is is to introduce a wrapper around the struct:

```
public class Ref<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Ref(T value) => Value = value;
}
```

And instead of trying to pass a `ref` to the class constructor - pass a `Ref<MovingAverageSettings>` object.

That way your struct can be immutable, and you would just replace the entire struct when it needs to change. You can also add an event that is raised when the value is set, to let any form know if it needs to update itself to show the updated value.

But I would change your struct to a class, there is a lot of limitations and pitfalls with structs in c#, you can get some information in the article from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct?redirectedfrom=MSDN